# Matplot lib hist does not shown the bell curve as expected

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to do a simple histogram with a data set of prices. I expect to see a bell curve indicating the high and low frequency of price. However, what I got is just one bin... Please help!

[image: my data]

matplot histogram output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my data has some enormous outlier value, that why the histogram has such shape. I sliced off some of those value and the histogram starts to appear normal

[image: removing some of the outlier values]